# Programtical user creation in Salesforce

Tags: provisioning

I have a trial account in Salesforce.
I want to know if it is possible to create a user account in Salesforce programitically using the trial account. 
If yes, please share the link for the same.

Regards,
Shelly

Comment: Do you mean can we create a User using Apex?

Comment: When you say a trial account do you mean an trial edition, if so which Salesforce edition is it on - enterprise. professional, etc

Answer (score 0):

we can create user through apex. here is the code.

```
User u = new user();
u.LastName = 'Test Code';
u.Email = 'test@test.com';
u.Alias = 'Tcode';
u.Username = 'test1234444@test.com';
u.CommunityNickname = 'test12';
u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT';
u.ProfileID = '00e90000000oyi5';
u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
insert u;
```